# iOS: How to stop screen layout distortion because of Keyboard?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, uikeyboard

I want to stop the Keyboard from distorting/resizing my layout in my phonegap application. I have used the following native android code to disable and enable resize in the application using a Cordova Plugin:

```
this.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        context.getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    }
});
```

However I have no idea how to do the same in iOS(6 & 7). Can anyone provide a snippet that I can use? Or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is available in the [Cordova Keyboard plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/keyboard). You can then either add a preference to the main Cordova config.xml...

```
<preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="false" />
```

...or call the corresponding method on the created global `Keyboard` object:

```
window.Keyboard.shrinkView(false);
```

Comment: I should add that in my case I ended up not using this feature, but instead hiding the offending elements (a bottom fixed footer) with a CSS class applied when the keyboard is visible.

Comment: I'm gonna give this a try and report back if it works for me :)